# "no block given" when programmatically defining around_ callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to write a library that will programmatically add `around_update`/`around_destroy` callbacks to a ActiveRecord model.

So, a regular model would look like this and it works as expected:

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  around_update :test_update

  def test_update
    Rails.logger.debug "test_update"
    yield
    Rails.logger.debug "Finished test_update"
  end
end

u=User.last
u.name = 'something'
u.save

######### output (as expected):
# test_update
# Finished test_update
```

My little library (obviously just the skeleton) looks like this:

```ruby
# A module for creating around callbacks in a model
module Piddle
  module TimelineFor
    def self.included(klass)
      klass.send(:extend, ClassMethods)
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def timeline_for(event, opts={})
        method_name = :"timeline_for_#{event.to_s}"
        define_method(method_name) do |&block|
          Rails.logger.debug method_name.to_s
          yield block
          Rails.logger.debug "After yield in #{method_name.to_s}"
        end

        send(:around_update, method_name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It defined a timeline_for method which should add the timeline_for_update method and make that a callback for the around_update event. And the User model I want to use is this:

```ruby
# second version of the User model using Piddle to create the callback
require 'piddle/piddle'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Piddle::TimelineFor

  timeline_for :update
end

u=User.last
u.name = 'gfgfhfhfgh'
u.save
```

In the output I see

```ruby
timeline_for_update
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
from /vagrant/lib/piddle/piddle.rb:13:in `block in timeline_for'
```

The first output line indicates that the method is being called but the block isn't being passed in.

Any ideas or alternative implementations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if you call `yield` from your `define_method`, ruby interprets that as trying to yield to the (nonexistant) block that was passed to `timeline_for`, not the block
that rails passed to `timeline_for_foo`

You've got `block` being passed to you so you can just call it:

```
def timeline_for event
  method_name = "timeline_for_#{event}"
  define_method method_name do |&block|
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.debug "before #{method_name} yield" 
    block.call
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.debug "after #{method_name} yield" 
  end
  send :around_update, method_name.to_sym #must use a symbol here
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works for me. Once it has been pointed out to me, it's kinda blindingly obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to define stuff like that. have a look at active-support concern.

i think that you need to call the around-filter on the class instead of using send in the definition itself:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Concern

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about AS::Concern. I definitely cleans the code up a bit but the fundamental problem remains. For reference, I was basing my code on [Timeline_fu](https://github.com/jamesgolick/timeline_fu/blob/master/lib/timeline_fu/fires.rb) which works fine but only with after_ not around_ callbacks.

Comment: i think you should call the ```around_callback``` in the ```self.included``` hook.